# How can I drive the vector input of a texture in geometry nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

So I'd like to remap the texture generated by a noise texture node in geometry nodes, similar to how I'd do that in shader nodes by plugging texture coordinate+mapping into the vector input of the noise texture node. What would be the correct way to achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use a *Position* node, then do some vector math on that (I added an *Add* node after the *Position* node, and added the position data from an *Object Info* node to it, so the position of that other object modifies the position of my texture).